# How do I discriminate between two different object types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following code:

`function myFunction(x: { foo: number } | { bar: string }) {`

How can I write some code to determine whether `x` is the first or second type?

Things I've considered:

- Writing an `x is MyType` function to check for a `foo` property. Yes, I could do this, but it seems overkill for types that are only used as arguments to a single function.
- `if ((x as { foo: number}).foo) { let y = x as { foo: number }`. I could do this, but it defeats the point of a type system.
- Give them both a common `type` property. Again, seems like overkill for types that are only used as arguments for one function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *also* a work-around, but you can unify the fields of the types by extending your existing types with optional fields typed to `never` so that each type theoretically has every field possible in the union:

```
{ foo: number, bar?: never } | { bar: string, foo?: never }
```

By making the superset type contain all the fields you can run type checks like:

```
type CompletelyDisjointed = { foo: number, bar?:never } | { foo?: never, bar: string };

function myFunction(x: CompletelyDisjointed): string | number {
    if (typeof x.bar === 'string') {
        return x.bar;
    } else {
        return x.foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: You also can have original parameter type unmodified if you like and use compatible unified type in a separate assignment: `let tx : {foo?: number, bar?: string} = x;   if (typeof tx.foo !== 'undefined') { ...`. Also, it's never implied that union type is disjoint - x may well have both `foo` and `bar`. If you want it disjoint you have to use the exact form in the answer.

Comment: This is very clever. Hopefully a better solution comes along someday, but this seems suitable for now.